# Gulp taking long time to merge CSS files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Attached is my gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {                                                    
    // Compiling SASS to this file                                        
    mix.sass('app.scss');                                                 

    // Merge these files to one.                                          
    mix.styles([                                                          
        'vendor/bootstrap.css',                                           
        'app.css'                                                         
    ], null, 'public/css')                                                
});
```

The following are my `.scss` files. All of them are under 100 lines of code.

[image]

I started a timer for running `gulp` on my Homestead VM, and it takes 20 seconds to merge the files.

These are the console outputs:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/laravel    $ gulp
[01:43:04] Using gulpfile ~/Code/laravel/gulpfile.js
[01:43:04] Starting 'default'...
[01:43:04] Starting 'sass'...
[01:43:04] Running Sass: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
[01:43:06] Finished 'default' after 1.75 s
[01:43:06] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[01:43:06] Finished 'sass' after 2.01 s
[01:43:06] Starting 'styles'...
[01:43:06] Merging: public/css/vendor/bootstrap.css, public/css/app.css
[01:43:06] Finished 'styles' after 50 ms
```

The `2.01s` it says is grossly underestimated.

Could someone help me figure out why it takes so long for gulp to compile my S/CSS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is because I ran gulp in my Homestead VM. After installing gulp on my host machine (Mac OS X Yosemite), I could use `gulp watch` again, and `gulp` would compile in under 1 second.